# How to retain classes that is added via jQuery after fetching all the data via API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, bootstrap-4, ejs

Basically, what I want to do is keep the "active" class in the nav-link depending on the tab that is clicked. However, the issue is that, since I'm fetching data from an API (using node), it refreshes the page and reverts back to its original state. I've been researching and couldn't find an answer. Please help.

Here's what's happening:
https://streamable.com/o1edue

Here's my HTML/EJS code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="nav-item test">
    <a
      class="nav-link active"
      id="summer"
      aria-current="page"
      href="/season/2020/summer"
      >Summer</a
    >
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item test">
    <a class="nav-link" id="spring" href="/season/2020/spring">Spring</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item test">
    <a class="nav-link" id="fall" href="/season/2020/fall">Fall</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item test">
    <a class="nav-link" id="winter" href="/season/2020/winter">Winter</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<% for(let i = 0; i< animeSeason.anime.length; i++){ %>
<div class="row test">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
    <div class="card bg-dark text-white card-home">
      <a href="/season/<%= animeSeason.anime[i].title %>">
        <img
          src="<%= animeSeason.anime[i].image_url %>"
          class="card-img"
          alt="..."
        />
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <h5 class="card-title card-title-home">
            <%= animeSeason.anime[i].title %>
          </h5>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<% } %>
```

and here's my jQuery code:

```
$(".test .nav-link").click(function () {
    $(".test .nav-link").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a client side javascript (While the whole page refresh) you can use `.indexOf` on page load

```
$(() => {
  $('a.nav-link').filter((index , element) => {
    return window.location.href.indexOf($(element).attr('href')) > -1;
  }).addClass('active');
});
```

This is how it works

```js
var url = "https://mywebsite.com/facebook/anything";  // just for demo don't use it in your code // if you change facebook here with google or twitter it should active its `<a>`


$(() => {  //on document ready
  $('a.nav-link').filter((index , element) => {
    var The_href = $(element).attr('href');
    return url.indexOf(The_href) > -1;  // replace url with window.location.href
  }).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.nav-link{
  background : #eee;
  margin : 5px;
  padding : 5px;
}
.nav-link.active{
  background : red;
  color : #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="nav-link" href="/google/anything">Google</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="/facebook/anything">facebook</a>
<a class="nav-link" href="/twitter/anything">twitter</a>
```

Comment: Hello, I don't quite understand but tried the solution eitherways and didn't seem to work. 

"this.href" was returning undefined and

 console.log(window.location.href.indexOf(this.href) > -1);

returns a false value.

Comment: @Mohammed I tried the new solution in codeply and still doesn't seem to work. ;_;